# JavaFX TreeView's TreeCell full width

Tags: kotlin, javafx, treeview

Hi stackoverflow communtiy,

I develop an app in kotlin with javafx. And for that I need a TreeView with custom TreeCell representation. My problem there is, that the TreeCell content is always left (see picture below). What I'm trying to do is, that the TreeCell content is stretched from left to right. (Like in AnchorPane.leftAnchor = 0 and AnchorPane.rightAnchor = 0)

The fxml looks like this:

```
<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal"
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="de.bli.bla.blu.conrollers.MyController">
  <TreeView fx:id="treeView" showRoot="false" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
  </TreeView>
</VBox>
```

in the controller I call:

```
treeView?.setCellFactory { PositionTreeCell() }
```

PositionTreeCell is:

```
class PositionTreeCell : TreeCell<PositionEntryController>() {
override fun updateItem(item: PositionEntryController?, empty: Boolean) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty)
    if (empty || item == null) {
        text = null
        graphic = null
        contextMenu = null
    } else {
        text = null
        graphic = getPositionTreeCellGraphic(item)
        contextMenu = null
    }
}

private fun getPositionTreeCellGraphic(item: PositionEntryController): Node? {
    if (item is TypeA) {
        val loader = FXMLLoader()
        loader.resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Resources", Locale.getDefault())
        loader.setControllerFactory {
            item
        }
        val parent = loader.load<Parent>(javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/fxml/typeA.fxml"))
        return parent
    } else if (item is TypeB)
        return TODO()
    else
        return null
}
}
```

The custom template in fxml is:

```
<GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="800" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="de.bli.bla.blu.conrollers.PositionDefinitionController">
<Label fx:id="keyLabel"/>
<Label fx:id="positionNameLabel" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
<Label fx:id="piecePriceLabel" GridPane.columnIndex="2"/>
<Label fx:id="unitLabel" GridPane.columnIndex="3"/>

<columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints maxWidth="100"/>
    <ColumnConstraints/>
    <ColumnConstraints maxWidth="100"/>
    <ColumnConstraints maxWidth="50"/>
</columnConstraints>
<rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints/>
</rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

What it looks like:

[image]

What I've tried is to set the AnchorPane in PositionTreeCell, but this didn't work. Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Do you know how to correct it? Or have a link to a correct implementation, so that I can correct it?

Comment: The documentation of [`Cell#updateItem(T,boolean)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem(T,boolean)) shows how to properly override the method.

Comment: I corrected the function. Thanks for the link. It was very helpful!